# Why can magic cure some medical problems but not others?

Tags: harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

In *The Chamber of Secrets*, Harry falls off his broom during a Quidditch match and breaks his arm, then Lockhart removes Harry's arm bones entirely while trying to mend it. When he's taken to the infirmary, they give him Skele-Gro to grow his bones back.

Why can magic regrow Harry's missing bones but can't fix his poor vision?

Comment: Why can we give someone a new hip joint but not cure cancer?  I know magic looks like it can do anything, but perhaps it can't.  Also I wear glasses knowing full well I could pay for laser correction - I chose to do it partially as I like glasses as a style accessory.

Comment: See [Why does Harry Potter wear glasses?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3722/98028) on SFF - it just seems some stuff is not that curable

Comment: Look on the bright side. His glasses were repaired by Hermoine so many times.